# How to authorize Google app on an API Project in a specific domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am trying to take a GAE app and have it upload logging data, in CSV format, into Google Storage, and then into Big Query (via an upload job).  The documentation says that the proper way to authorize a GAE app to have write permission in an API project is to add the GAE application as a team member in the API project.

However, there is a domain restriction in the API Team panel, that makes it impossible for us to add the '@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' address that the documentation says we need to.  I talked with our IT department (who setup the API Project to being with) and they aren't sure how to circumvent that restriction.

I must be missing something, but how should we authorize our GAE App to push data into our API Project when we cannot add the account in this manner?

Thanks.

Comment: More info:  we also attempted to add the @appspot.gserviceaccount.com to a google group, and then added the new group to the API Project.  However, we still encountered the error...

Comment: This is the error we are seeing: 
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/log-bucket%3Aproduction-health-dev/jobs?alt=json returned "Access Denied: Job log-bucket:production-health-dev:job_dac84028806d440cb1cffe2610a67aa2: RUN_JOB">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a Google group on your domain.
2. Add that group email address to the team editors in your Google Developers project.
3. Then add the Google App Engine application email address to that Group.

You might have to wait a short time before the permissions kick in.

Comment: Thanks Michael!  Worked like a charm.